# Does $f(x)=x^{3/2}$ has a taylor expansion?

Tags: convergence-divergence, power-series, taylor-expansion

The question is:

Prove or disprove:

The function $f(x)=x^{3/2}$ has a power series expansion about $x_0=0$ with positive radius of convergence.

When I start calculating the derivative of the k'th order:

$f'(x)=3/2\cdot x^{1/2}$

$f''(x)=3/2\cdot 1/2 \cdot x^{-1/2}$

..

For every $K>=0$ derivative, $f^{k}(0)=0$

Does this mean, that this function doesn't have a taylor expansion? (and linking to this question - it doesn't have a radius of convergence) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some hints:

I think you might want to check your claim about $f''(0)$ being zero.

Also: is $f(x)$ defined for $x < 0$?

Comment: Oh you are right. f''(0) doesn't even exists. It means there is no expansion?

Answer (score 1):

Well, $f(x)$ is only defined for $x \ge 0$.

Also, $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to 0+}f''(x)=+\infty$, careful.

Taylor Series are for infinitely differentiable functions.

Comment: You're right. The limit that you wrote, What does it mean? As I see it, it is supposed to be 0.

Taylor series are infinitely differentiable functions, and I can differentiate my function infinite times, no?

Comment: @sheldonzy Certainly you can apply the power rule, quotient rule, etc. infinitely many times in this case, but each time your resulting derivative may not be defined. For this particular example, your function is defined for all $x \geq 0$, and so is its first derivative, but its second derivative isn't defined at $x=0$. Since $f''$ is defined in less places than $f$, it's not infinitely differentiable, and you shouldn't expect the Taylor series about $0$ to work.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Expand $f(t)=(1+t)^{3/2}$ to Maclaurin series, then replace $t=-1+x.$

Note: The Taylor series of $f(x)=x^{3/2}$ does not exist at $x_0=0$, because $f\notin C^{\infty}$. However, it can be safely calculated for $x_0>0$ if $(1+x)^{3/2}$ is expanded to Taylor series at $x_0=0$.

Comment: this is not a series expansion about $0$, as required. Moreover the Taylor expansion could not converge when $|x-x_0|=\rho$

Comment: @enzotib, thank you. I clarified the point.